# my php file doesnt link to css when i clean url using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I use rewrite rules to clean my URL, I can't access my CSS files. Without the rewrite rules my page works fine, but with the rewrite rules images,CSS and JS documents cannot be linked. What could be the problem?

My `.htaccess` codes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php  
RewriteRule ^product_details/([0-9]+) product_details.php?id=$1
```

Now I don't understand why my `edit.php` is unable to locate external files even though it loads from the correct path on server-side (`mysite.com/`). And it does not show the URL in an extra directory (in this case `mysite.com/e/`).

Comment: Use an abosolute path for your relative links eg


`/style.css` instead of `style.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod Rewrite will redirect *www.example.com/product_details/123* to *product_details.php?id=123* on server-side.

Your browser thinks that */product_details/* points to a directory and resolves relative links accordingly.

The solution is to use absolute paths or add `<base href="//www.example.com/">` to your html head element.